# WCF service and adding custom Identity claims

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I created some claims and attach them thread, then I want to access operation contract GetCurrentUser(); user email claim always return null.

Where is the problem?

WCF using Local IIS and binding type is wsHttpBinding.

```
<serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
              customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="SampleService.UserValidator, SampleService" />
</serviceCredentials>
```

Custom Validator;

```
public class UserValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (userName == null || password == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (userName == password)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "AbbA"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "foo@bar.com"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"Customer")
                };

            var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Sample");
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(id);

            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new FaultException("Wrong Password...");
        }
    }
}
```

And My OperationContract;

```
    public string GetCurrentUser()
    {
        var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

        if (principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var cp = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
            var email = cp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value; <<<< It's return always null :(

            return string.Format("Your Email is:{0}", email);
        }
        else
        {
            return "NONE";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, so;

I used WCF Forms authentication with Wif and session authentication module (SAM)

You can find information and sample;

http://brockallen.com/2013/01/26/replacing-forms-authentication-with-wifs-session-authentication-module-sam-to-enable-claims-aware-identity/

Other option Enable WCF Authentication Service;

1) https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb398990

2) https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/bb398862%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

3) https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/bb398778%28v=vs.100%29.aspx