# WCF custom auth using session id

Tags: c#, wcf, session, authentication, authorization

I need to create a custom authentication/authorization on an existing WCF service, which should be per-method: some methods should force user to log in, and other should allow anonymous usage. The service is implemented as singleton.

To do so, I want to do the following:

- enable sessions with default behaviour, so each of the existing service methods will be initiating session in case it doesn't exist;
- add login(userName, password) method, which will keep a successful login artefact in a wrapper around `Dictionary<>`, with current session id used as a key;
- add `logout()` method which closes the session and removes the artefact from the dictionary;
- add sessions monitor which will use `Dictionary<SessionId, WeakReference<OperationContext.Current>>` to drop sessions, for which the `logout()` method was not called. The monitor will be executed each time a new session is added.

There are two questions though:

1. Is there a simpler method to achieve per-method auth?
2. Are there any problems with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haved a similar problem a few days ago and I found a solution.

You can check if you want;
[WCF service and adding custom Identity claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611641/wcf-service-and-adding-custom-identity-claims)

Answer (score 0):

For custom authorization you should use [Custom Authorization Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731774(v=vs.110).aspx). You should manage sessions with ASP.net which you can have access if you enable AspNet Compatibility.